# Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have used `import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';` in my Router.js

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import EmployeeList from './components/EmployeeList';
import EmployeeCreate from './components/EmployeeCreate';

const RouterComponent = StackNavigator(
{
  LoginForm: {
    screen: LoginForm,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Please Login'
    }
  },
  EmployeeList: {
    screen: EmployeeList,
  },
  EmployeeCreate: {
    screen: EmployeeCreate,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Create Employee'
    }
  }
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'LoginForm',
}
);

export default RouterComponent;
```

Of course i use it in my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './src/reducers';
import Router from './src/Router';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

And i can use `this.props.navigation` in my `LoginForm.js` like this function:

```
  onButtonPress() {
    const { email, password, navigation } = this.props;

    this.props.loginUser({ email, password, navigation });
  }
```

I pass navigation to my Action file , i can use it to navigate another screen , like this:

```
const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, user, navigation) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    payload: user
  });
  //navigation is from LoginForm.js , navigate to EmployeeList is working
  navigation.navigate('EmployeeList');
};
```

Now i try to use `this.props.navigation.navigate` in my ListItem.js

My `ListItem` is under `EmployeeList.js`

Here is my `EmployeeList.js`

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { View, Text, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { employeesFetch } from '../actions';
import ListItem from './ListItem';

class EmployeeList extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'EmployeeList',
    headerLeft: null,
    headerRight: <Button title="Add" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('EmployeeCreate')} />,
  });

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.employeesFetch(); 
  }
  // Using ListItem over here
  renderRow(employee) {
    return <ListItem employee={employee} />;
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.props.employees}
        renderItem={this.renderRow}
        keyExtractor={employee => employee.uid}
      />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const employees = _.map(state.employees, (val, uid) => {
    return { ...val, uid };
  });

  return { employees };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { employeesFetch })(EmployeeList);
```

Here is my problem use `this.props.navigation.navigate` in ListItem.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import { CardSection } from './common';

class ListItem extends Component {

  onRowPress() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('EmployeeCreate');
  }

  render() {
    const { item } = this.props.employee;
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.onRowPress.bind(this)}>
        <View>
          <CardSection>
            <Text style={styles.titleSytle}>
              {item.name}
            </Text>
          </CardSection>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  titleSytle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 15
  }
};

export default ListItem;
```

I can use `this.props.navigation` in my LoginForm.js , i can't figure it out why i use it in ListItem.js navigate is undefined ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in file `EmployeeList.js` pass navigation as prop to ListItem.

```
renderRow(employee) {
  return <ListItem employee={employee} navigation={this.props.navigation} />;
}
```

Now you should be able to access navigation using `this.props.navigation` inside `ListItem.js`.

> Just an observation, never bind methods to context inside the render
>   function as it is called repeatedly and a new instance will be created
>   each time. Change your `ListItem.js` as below.

```
class ListItem extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onRowPress = this.onRowPress.bind(this);  // here we bind it
  }

  onRowPress() {
    this.props.navigation && this.props.navigation.navigate('EmployeeCreate');
  }

  render() {
    const { item } = this.props.employee;
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.onRowPress}>
        <View>
          <CardSection>
            <Text style={styles.titleSytle}>
              {item.name}
            </Text>
          </CardSection>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when i try your code , it will show error `Cannot read property navigation of undefined`

Comment: No problem, let's try to debug your code. Where does this error originate, EmployeeList.js or ListItem.js. Can you put a breakpoint or console.log(this.props) to verify the value of props in both the cases.

Comment: Thans you agian . I find it just a little bit issue have to fix it .  I console.log in`renderRow(employee) {console.log(this.props);}` it shows undefined.
But i console.log in EmployeeList render function , i can see Object employees and navigaion.  Now i don't know how to pass navigation to renderRow function.  Any idea ?

Comment: Perfect we're making progress. Can you use the code snippet above to add a constructor to EmployeeList.js class and bind renderRow function (similar to onRowPress above). Then do a console.log and revert.

Comment: Yes ! Try the code with your example in `constructor` and console log(this.props) under renderRow can see the Object navigation. Finally i can pass it to ListItem.js and use navigate.  Thank you Rishabh . Help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use `withNavigation`. In your `ListItem.js` file add `import { withNavigation } from ‘react-navigation’;` and replace `export default ListItem;` with `export default withNavigation(ListItem);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did (using latest react native with ES6):

Refactored the class code from this:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   // content & code
}
```

To look like this:

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   // content & code
}
export default withNavigation(MyComponent);
```

According to the docs ([withNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html)):

"withNavigation is a higher order component which passes the navigation prop into a wrapped component."